# Why the column name is missing in pandas output in the group by result?

Tags: pandas

Update

if use **to_frame()** the column name seems not in the same row

```
            重量
型号
HG-R2075  2040
HG220      680
```

This is my code, it groups the "型号"(which means **type**), and get the sum of the "重量"(**weight**) and exclude the column("是否发送") with a value in it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(script_dir ) # change to the path that you already know

try:
   ClientName = sys.argv[1]
except :
   print(u'没有输入或者错误的客户名称!')

df = pd.read_excel("Summary.xlsm")
df = df[df['客户'].str.contains(ClientName)][pd.isnull(df[u"是否已经发送"])].groupby([ u'型号'])[u'重量'].sum()
print('[CQ:face,id=21] ' + '*' * 10 + u'以下是' + ClientName + u'未发送的重量' + '*' * 10 + '[CQ:face,id=21]')
print(str(df))
```

Output is this :

```
[CQ:face,id=21] **********以下是KATUN未发送的重量**********[CQ:face,id=
21]
型号        (****the column name is missing here*****)
HG-R2075    2040
HG220        680
Name: 重量, dtype: int64
```

I don't know why the column name is missing?

The output I want is this: how to make it?

```
型号        重量
HG-R2075    2040
HG220        680
Name: 重量, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with chaining by `&`.

If need 2 column `DataFrame` add `as_index=False` or [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
mask = df['客户'].str.contains(ClientName) & df[u"是否已经发送"].isnull()
df = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'], as_index=False)[u'重量'].sum()
```

Or:

```
df = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'])[u'重量'].sum().reset_index()
```

For one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) - first column is `index`:

```
df = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'])[u'重量'].sum().to_frame()
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(345)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'客户':np.random.choice(list('abc'), size=N),
                   u"是否已经发送":np.random.choice([np.nan,0], size=N),
                   u'型号':np.random.randint(2, size=N),
                   u'重量':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
print (df)
   型号 客户  是否已经发送  重量
0   0  a     0.0   4
1   0  a     0.0   0
2   1  b     NaN   8
3   1  b     NaN   5
4   1  c     0.0   6
5   1  a     NaN   3
6   1  a     NaN   3
7   1  b     0.0   4
8   0  a     NaN   2
9   1  c     NaN   8
```

---

```
ClientName = 'a'
mask = df['客户'].str.contains(ClientName) & df[u"是否已经发送"].isnull()
df1 = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'], as_index=False)[u'重量'].sum()
print(df1)
   型号  重量
0   0   2
1   1   6

df1 = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'])[u'重量'].sum().reset_index()
print(df1)
   型号  重量
0   0   2
1   1   6

df2 = df[mask].groupby([ u'型号'])[u'重量'].sum().to_frame()
print (df2)
    重量
型号    
0    2
1    6
```

Answer (score 3):

The result `df` of your `groupby` operation is actually a Series, not a DataFrame. That's why it is printed with a different format.

`print(df.to_frame())` should to the trick.

EDIT: Actually in such a dataframe index name and column name will not be printed on the same row. To get a cleaner output, use `reset_index` to get 2 proper columns:

`print(df.reset_index().to_string(index=False))`

Comment: I update my post, if use to_frame() the column name seems not in the same row